# Adding pop-open JS slider to a menu list - link not working

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a hamburger icon that triggers a pop-out JS window - and I want it add it to a list menu. This code works:

```
    <div class="header-top-first clearfix">
        <ul class="social-links clearfix hidden-xs">
            <li><img src="../_img/icon_hamburger.png" class="nav-toggler toggle-slide-left"></li>

            <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li class="linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
```

BUT I want the HAMBURGER  to NOT be an image, rather an FA icon as shown below. My question is - as it is coded below, the link no longer works?

```
     <div class="header-top-first clearfix">
    <ul class="social-links clearfix hidden-xs">    
        <!-- I am trying to replace the hamburger image here but the pop-open link no longer works -->
        <li class="nav-toggler toggle-slide-left"><a href="#" class="nav-toggler toggle-slide-left"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></li>

        <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li class="linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Any suggestions on how I can add it to the list as fa-bars and still have the pop-open work?

Comment: You can see it at: http://www.mondrianhp.com/dmeyers/index2.php?user=dmeyers#

Comment: Can you provide runnable source code?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `</a>` tag between `</i></li>`